# Find the minimum number of steps that we can arrange coins according to their weight

Tags: combinatorics

We have $20$ coins every step we can give $10$ coins to a person and he will tell us the order of their weights.Find the minimum number of steps that we can arrange coins according to their weight.

**My attempt**:I found a method using $5$ steps.

> 1.Divide the coins to two equal halfs and give one of the halfs to that person.
>
> 2.Give the second half to that person.
>
> 3.Give $5$ heavy coins from the first step and $5$ heavy coins from the second step to that person.
>
> 4.Do the same as third step but this time use the $5$ light coins of step $1$,$2$
>
> 5.Give $5$ light coins from the third step and $5$ heavy coins from the forth step to that person.

I checked few cases it worked but I can't prove $5$ is the minimum and I can't prove it always works.

Puzzling SE copy of the problem is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54040/find-the-minimum-number-of-steps-that-we-can-arrange-coins-according-to-their-we).

And AOPS copy of the problem is [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1487977p8719433).

Source:Second round iranian olympiad of informatics.

Comment: Theoretically, just from counting, it _could_ be possible with only three steps. This comes from the fact that there are $20!$ different ways the coins can be arranged, and for each step, you potentially pick out $\frac{1}{10!}$ of those. Three such optimal steps, and you're down to only one possible arrangement left. As for whether it's actually possible, I don't know, and it sounds unlikely.

Comment: In 1965 this puzzle was making the rounds at IBM: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55618.html, +1 for the memory!

Comment: @FredKline They are different here we want to find the order of their weight not the heaviest it needs more steps.

Answer (score 1):

For a proof that your procedure works:

Let the result of steps 1 and 2 be

$$A_1 \ge A_2 \ge \dots \ge A_{10}$$

and

$$B_1 \ge B_2 \ge \dots \ge B_{10}$$

The result of step 3 will be some permutation of

$$A_1, A_2, \dots, A_5, B_1, B_2, \dots, B_5$$

The result of step 4 will be some permutation of

$$A_6, A_7, \dots, A_{10}, B_6, B_7, \dots, B_{10}$$

If $B_j$ was the lightest of the heaviest 5 coins from step $3$, then it is easy to see that $j \le 5$: The 5 heaviest are $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_{5-j}, B_1, B_2, B_j$

Similarly if $B_k$ was the heaviest of the lightest 5 from step 4, then $k \ge 6$.

Thus you have a partition by weight

> Heaviest in step 3 >= Lightest 5 in step 3, Heaviest 5 in step 4 >=
>   Lightest 5 in step 4

You step 5 now sorts the middle portion and brings everything in order.

Comment: Now why $5$ is the minimum?

Comment: It can be easily proved that we need more than $2$ steps But we should prove that it can't be done using $3$ or $4$ steps.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: No idea. I added the answer so that I can come back to it later when/if I get an answer to the other question.

Comment: I copied your answer to puzzling SE mentioning your name I hope it doesn't matter.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: No worries. I can't even sue you if I wanted to :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not contain the proof you ask for, but a number of thoughts and observations about the problem which are too long to fit in a comment. I'm writing this up in the hope that it can help someone else to avoid going down the incorrect paths that I did.

Firstly, here is an incorrect argument for why at least 5 is needed. In a set of 20 coins, there are $\binom{20}{2}=20\cdot19/2=190$ pairs that need to be ranked. In a comparison of 10 coins, $\binom{10}{2}=10\cdot9/2=45$ pairs are ranked. Therefore we need at least $\lceil{190/45}\rceil = 5$ steps.

Unfortunately this is argument bogus, since not every pair needs to be directly compared in order to be ranked. If $a<b$ and $b<c$, we can deduce $a<c$ without actually checking.

There is a second argument that is also bogus. If you have 4 items, and can compare any two of them against each other, and can swap them if they are in the wrong order, then the minimum number of pairwise comparisons/swap to sort 4 items is 5. The way to do this is as follows:

 Put the items in a row and name the four locations $A,B,C,D$.

Sort $\{A,B\}$ as well as $\{C,D\}$, so we have $A<B$, $C<D$.

Then sort $\{A,C\}$ and also $\{B,D\}$, so that $A<C$ and $B<D$.

Now we have $A<\{B,C\}<D$, and a final sort of $\{B,C\}$ orders them.

Note that the given 5-step solution for 20 coins is exactly this procedure applied to 4 sets of 5 coins. Therefore, 5 steps are necessary in order to sort 4 sets of 5 coins.

This argument is insufficient, because it assumes that we have to restrict ourselves to sets of 5 coins which are pairwise compared and sorted. It does not automatically follow that any other selections of coins to sort at each step could not lead to a shorter solution.

This second argument made me think that it may be possible that for any algorithm that uses only four 10-coin comparison steps, some set of 4 coins could be found that could not possibly have been sorted because only pairwise comparisons had been made on the 4 coins and you need at least 5 of those to always be able to sort them. Unfortunately this makes the same mistake as the first bogus argument. Some of the comparisons involving other coins might provide enough information to sort the set of 4 coins with fewer than 5 pairwise comparisons between them.

To gain a better feel for the problem I wrote a computer program to brute-force some smaller variants.

Let $n$ be the total number of coins to be sorted (i.e. 20 in the original problem).

Let $k$ be the number of coins that are compared in each step (i.e. 10 in the original problem).

Let $s$ be the number of $k$-coin comparisons .

Here are the shortest solutions it found:

```
k  n  s    Example solution
2  2  1    01
2  3  3    01 02 12
2  4  5    01 23 02 13 12
2  5  9    01 02 03 04 12 34 13 24 23

k  n  s 
3  3  1    012
3  4  3    012 013 023
3  5  4    012 013 014 234
3  6  6    012 345 134 013 235 234
3  7  6    012 345 146 013 256 234

k  n  s 
4  4  1    0123
4  5  3    0123 0124 0234
4  6  3    0123 0145 2345
4  7  4    0123 0456 1245 3456
4  8  5    0123 4567 0145 2367 2345

k  n  s
5  5  1    01234
5  6  3    01234 01235 02345
5  7  3    01234 01256 03456
5  8  4    01234 01235 01267 34567
5  9  5    01234 01235 01678 02367 45678
5 10  6?   01234 56789 23789 01256 01489 34567
5 11  6?   01234 56789 2378A 01256 0489A 34567

k  n  s
6  6  1    012345
6  7  3    012345 012346 012356
6  8  3    012345 012367 014567
6  9  3    012345 012678 345678
6 10  4    012345 012367 012389 456789
6 11  5?   012345 56789A 012345 123678 456789
6 12  5?   012345 6789AB 012678 3459AB 345678
```

The ones with a question mark have not been fully calculated through due to time constraints, so solutions with fewer steps may exist.

It was only when I saw the results of the $n=5$ $k=2$ case that I realised that I made the assumption that the later steps do not depend on the results of previous steps. It is always possible to sort 5 items using at most 7 pairwise comparisons, not the 9 shown in the table.

If you have $A<B<C$ and an unknown $D$ then you can use a binary search to find the right place to insert $D$ in two comparisons instead of three. First compare $D$ with $B$, and depending on the outcome compare it with either $A$ or $C$. This allows 5 items to be sorted using only 7 comparisons instead of 9, because it involves two such insertions.

Essentially the results in the table above are for the shortest [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network), where coins at fixed locations are compared and sorted. The best sorting network for 5 items does indeed have 9 comparisons/swaps.

It is not inconceivable that a shorter strategy exists without this assumption, but that makes it a lot harder to analyse than it already is.

There could well be a straightforward proof that 5 steps is minimal, but I have not been able to find it yet.